# 'var' keyword in c#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C# ‘var’ keyword versus explicitly defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429446/c-var-keyword-versus-explicitly-defined-variables)
>   [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)

May I know where to use 'var' keyword and the purpose of using that there ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just check one of the many links here : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+var+keytword ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the var keyword to infer the type of an object.

For example:

```
//without using the "var" keyword
Dictionary<List<string>,int> myCustomDictionary = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>();

//with the "var" keyword
var myCustomDictionary = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>();
```

Which is easier to read? :)